# getting list from django views to googlecharts in templates

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I am trying to get sensor data from postgresql database to googlecharts in django, but I am unable to get the charts though data shows when I write {{ sensor_data }} in template. Can anyone tell what I am doing wrong here, this is the template:

```
<html>
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    google.charts.load('current', {packages: ['corechart']});
    google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);


    function drawChart() {
      // Define the chart to be drawn.
      var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
      data.addColumn('datetime','Date/Time');
      data.addColumn('number','Temperature');
      {% for data in sensor_data %}
    data.addRow([new Date("{{ data.data_date }}"), {{ data.amb_temp }}]);
      {% endfor %}  

      var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('myPieChart'));
      chart.draw(data, null);
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>

<div id="myPieChart" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
    <a href="/polls/{{node.id }}/"></a>

</body>
</html>
```

this is the view:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import unicode_literals


from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseForbidden
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
from .models import *
import json
from django.core.serializers.json import DjangoJSONEncoder

def date_handler(obj):
    if hasattr(obj, 'isoformat'):
        return obj.isoformat()
    else:
        return obj

def history(request,node):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        try:           
            crop=bitter_gourd_node_c.objects.filter(node_id=node).values_list('data_date','amb_temp')   
        sensor_data = []
            if crop:
                for i in range(0, len(crop)):
                    sensor_data.append([crop[i]])
            json_list = json.dumps(sensor_data, cls=DjangoJSONEncoder)
            return render(request,'history.html', {"sensor_data": reversed(json_list)})
        except Nodes.DoesNotExist:
            return HttpResponseForbidden

    return HttpResponseForbidden
```

and this is the model:

```
class bitter_gourd_node_c(models.Model):
    node_id=models.ForeignKey(Nodes)
    record_no= models.AutoField(blank=True,primary_key=True)    
    data_date=models.DateTimeField()
    humidity=models.DecimalField(max_digits=14,decimal_places=10)
    amb_temp=models.DecimalField(max_digits=14,decimal_places=10)
    deep_under_temp=models.DecimalField(max_digits=14,decimal_places=10)
    shallow_under_temp=models.DecimalField(max_digits=14,decimal_places=10)
    deep_soil_moisture=models.DecimalField(max_digits=14,decimal_places=10)
    shallow_soil_moisture=models.DecimalField(max_digits=14,decimal_places=10)
    ldr=models.DecimalField(max_digits=14,decimal_places=10)
```

Comment: i didn't quite get what is your issue. But i would suggest you try debugging if you get your expected values in the JS, for example in your for loop add a line "console.log()" and dome the date and the value so you make sure they are correct as you expect

Comment: Error: Row given with size different than 2 (the number of columns in the table). continuously getting this error, even though I checked on terminal the len(sensor_data[0]) function shows 2 as output.

Comment: Ok this means one of your values in loop have wrong or undefined value. Please try console.log(new Date("{{ data.data_date }}"), {{ data.amb_temp }}). Before addRow, to see which row is wrong

Answer (score 0):

Why are you converting sensor_data to JSON?

```
json_list = json.dumps(sensor_data, cls=DjangoJSONEncoder)
return render(request,'history.html', {"sensor_data": reversed(json_list)})
```

It is not necessary to convert it to json.

```
return render(request,'history.html', {"sensor_data": sensor_data})
```

Comment: without json I get this format:                                            "[(datetime.datetime(2017, 3, 13, 12, 7, 36, tzinfo=<UTC>), Decimal('22.0000000000')), (datetime.datetime(2017, 3, 11, 6, 5, 25, tzinfo=<UTC>), Decimal('25.0000000000'))]"                                       and with json i get this:                                              [["2017-03-13T12:07:36Z", "22.0000000000"], ["2017-03-11T06:05:25Z", "25.0000000000"]] I am not sure if the other format is supported.

Comment: Ok.  you should use "[template filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/templates/builtins/#built-in-template-tags-and-filters)". `new Date("{{ data.data_date |  date:'Y-m-d\TH:i:s\Z' }}"), {{ data.amb_temp | stringformat:'d' }}) `

Comment: Error: Row given with size different than 2 (the number of columns in the table). continuously getting this error, even though I checked on terminal the len(sensor_data[0]) function shows 2 as output.